# Ethernet connector and transformers

Tags: pic, communication, transformer, ethernet, microchip

I'm working on an Ethernet connection for a PIC18F4620 with the [ENC28J60](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en022889). I found a useful article [here](http://www.micro-examples.com/public/microex-navig/doc/094-ep2-ethernet.html), with a schematic:

[image]

I see I need transformers between the RJ45 connector and the Ethernet chip. I've heard people talking about connectors where the transformer already is included. I'm thinking of disassembling the connector from this board:

[image] [image]

My questions:

- Would this connector have built-in transformers? Or how can I check this?
- If the connector does not have built-in transformers, can I use the chip next to it for that? The numbers on it are "bel 0120S1B S558-5999-46" and a search for "S558-5999-46" returns [this](http://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/066/S558-5999-46-pdf.php). Would this "transformer module" be compatible with the ENC28J60?

Comment: I bet the connector doesn't have transformer inside and the bel part is the transformer. A commonly used term is `magnetic`, which can help you in your searches. You can use a multimeter on continuity to test the connector. If it does have transformer (popular term seems to be `magjack`), there won't be continuity between the pins which go to PCB and pins which mate with the 8P8C plug. I don't have enough experience to tell you what kind of transformer you need to use though.

Comment: Depending on what type on transmission you are doing, the transformers aren't even always necessary. I've heard of and seen (though never done myself) 10BaseT working without the magnetics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that jack is not a `Magjack`. It is a bare connector. I say that because the chip next to it is the Bel S558-5999-46. [It's specific datasheet is here](http://belfuse.com/pdfs/S558-5999-46-F.pdf). It is an Ethernet 10/100Base-T Lan Magnetic Single Port Transformer. You could use that. Or both the chip and the jack. It should be compatible with the ENC28J60, most common 10/100 magnetic transformer would. The S558-5999-46 is a 1:1 Ratio transformer. See the schematic below for tappings and pinout.

[image]

Comment: Not all ethernet tranformers will work with the ENC28J60.  It requires 1:1 ratio and at least a center tap on one of the windings on its side.  While 1:1 is the most common ratio, there are certainly others.  Different PHYs have different requirements.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I did say common, but double checking, the s558 there is a 1:1 transformer. As for the tap, I have included the schematic from the specific datasheet I found on Bel's site in an edit.

Comment: For further readers, S558-5999-46 transformer costs over $2 wholesale, more expensive than ENC28J60 chip itself. What's the point.

Answer (score 4):

The pictured RJ45 is not a magjack. The isolator component in that case is that thing next to the connector with the **bel** logo.

You will not be able to generally use "any old connector" and magnetic components for you Ethernet connection. There are multiple parameters to consider when selecting the magnetic for your application. (And when you do that selection I would highly recommend that you use a magjack type component).

The factors at play here are:

1) Coupling ratio across the magnetic coils between the PHY connections and the CAT5/6 cable.

2) Common mode magnetics for noise filtering.

3) Overall number of coils in the magjack.

4) PHY side common pin biasing - to a voltage rail or to GND.

5) Termination resistor placement and values on the PHY side of the magnetics.

6) Filter capacitor placement and values used on the PHY side.

7) Ethernet connection type / speed.

8) Number of wire pairs used in the RJ45 used to make the actual type of Ethernet connection you are trying to build.

Note that it is fairly common that manufacturers of magjacks will provide information on which components in their line will be recommended for various PHYs and popular Ethernet controllers that have the PHY built on board the chip.

Answer (score 3):

I followed the link to the BEL part, but that just went to some Mouser page, no datasheet.

Most likely, the BEL part is the transformer.  The ENC28J60 requires 1:1 transformers with at least one of the windings center tapped on its side.  I usually use a Pulse H2019.  That also includes common mode chokes on the network side, which can be useful in reducing emissions on the ethernet cable.

By the way, I don't use the ENC28J60 much anymore, especially if it's going to be driven from a PIC 18.  In that case, use the PIC 18F67J60 instead, which essentially has the ENC28J60 built in.  All you need is the PIC, the transformer, a few passive parts, and the RJ-45 jack.

Comment: The last time I checked, there wasn't a price advantage to the PIC18F67J60 approach. One advantage of using the ENC28J60 is you can power it off, which I don't think is possible with the integrated PIC. Is it?

Comment: @kenny: Not at all. The ENC28J60 costs $2.13 (all 1k prices from microchipdirect) and the 18F67J60 only $3.47. Compare to a 18F67J50 at $2.97, the ethernet MAC/PHY only adds $.50. Some of the older 5V 18F parts, like the '4520 cost *more* than the '67J60. Then it's not all about price anyway. Board space and overall size can be good things too, plus with tighter access to the internal MAC/PHY, the net stack runs faster and doesn't use up extra pins for the SPI bus.

Comment: For other readers: Pulse H2019 got discontinued and PIC18F67J60 costs over $7. ENC28J60 is still $2.